# Trouble outputting vector to .txt file

Tags: c++, class, vector, reference

I've been struggling with this for some time now and I'm finally reaching out for help. I'm reading in data from a text file via the readData function. Within that function I'm calling a function of the ELement Class to read in Element data to a vector of vectors. I'm then then trying to write the data to a text file via the writeData function, and this is where my problem is. When I compile and run, the outputfile contains all other data that I'm writing to it except the Element data. I also need to be able to access this Element data via other functions.

Any help, tips, or insight would be greatly appreciated. I've included what I believe is the pertinent code below. If more is necessary, just let me know.

Thanks!

readData Function:

```
void readData::readdata(ifstream &inp)
{

    Element r;

    r.addelementdata(inp);

};
```

addelementdata Function:

```
void Element::addelementdata(istream& inp) 
{
    int i,j,tmp;

    for (i = 0; i < d_numElems; i++)
    {
        vector<int>row;
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            inp >> tmp;
            row.push_back(tmp);

        }
    elems_matrix.push_back(row);
    }

}
```

output matrix contents Function:

```
void Element::Elems_matrix_contents(ofstream& out)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < d_numElems; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            out << elems_matrix[i][j] << '\t';
        }
    }
}
```

Element Class:

```
class Element: public readData
{
protected:
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > elems_matrix;

public:
    // Constructors
    Element();

    //Destructor
    ~Element(){};
    // Functions
    void addelementdata(istream&inp);

    std::vector<std::vector < int >> elems_matrix_copy;

    void Elems_matrix_contents(ofstream& out);

};
```

readData Class:

```
class readData 
{
public:

    readData();

    ~readData(){};

    void readdata(ifstream &inp);
    void writedata(ofstream &out);

};
```

writeData Function:

```
void readData::writedata(ofstream &out)
{

    out << "ELEMENT  " << "Material  " << "Nodes:  "<< endl;

    Element r;

    r.Elems_matrix_contents(out);

    out << "*******************************************************************" << endl << endl;
};
```

Comment: It might help if you include the `writedata()` function code as you say that is the function that is not working.

Comment: I apologize, I've add the writeData function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The ability to prepare [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be of great use to you. I am voting to close because when this question is reduced to a minimal example, it has nothing to do with files, writing, or vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you create a local variable of type `Element` and read the data into that. Because it is local it is destroyed at the end of the function:

```
void readData::readdata(ifstream &inp)
{

    Element r; // this will die at end of function

    r.addelementdata(inp);

};
```

Same with your `writedata()` function. You create a brand new (empty) `Element` and output that:

```
void readData::writedata(ofstream &out)
{

    out << "ELEMENT  " << "Material  " << "Nodes:  "<< endl;

    Element r; // completely new contains nothing

    r.Elems_matrix_contents(out);

    out << "********************************************" << endl << endl;
};
```

Perhaps you should make `Element r` a member of the class `readData`?

```
class readData
{
    Element r; // now all functions can use the same Element

    // ... blah blah blah
};
```